# Why withdraw api call give me error..?

Tags: php, bitcoin

When I am fire withdraw fund mkraken api call it'll give me error like below here is my api call which I have used

**Code :**

```
$res = $kraken->QueryPrivate('Withdraw', 
                                    array(
                                        'asset' => 'XXBT',
                                        'key' => 'Mykey',
                                        'amount'=> '0.000121',
                                    )
                             );
```

**Response Error:**

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => EFunding:Invalid amount
        )

)
```

Any one have idea why it'll give me error or what I am missing...?

Comment: What currency allows you to withdraw `0.000121` try it with `1.00`

Comment: @RiggsFolly : Why 1.00, I am passing XXBT value in request, Is their any restriction..?

Comment: `EFunding:Invalid amount` So try another amount that looks normal/sensible

Comment: @RiggsFolly : it'll give same error..

Comment: Well then we will have learned something

Comment: I guess it did not give the same error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the *Funding -> Withdraw -> Bitcoin (XBT)* tab you can see that the least amount for a Bitcoin withdrawal is `฿0.00100`. Try something above that amount.